# Не выполняется задание, добавленное в очередь Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Создал тестовое задание:

```
class FindRatingJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  def perform(*args)
    puts 'OK!'
  end
end
```

Вызываю его в application controller:

```
FindRatingJob.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later
```

В логи выводится сообщение, что задание добавленно в очередь:

*[ActiveJob] Enqueued FindRatingJob (Job ID: 5a307b83-4f8f-4513-af7f-1d75cddf5198) to Sidekiq(default) at 2018-04-03 13:21:06 UTC*.

Но ничего больше не происходит. При этом вызов *perform_now* дает нужный результат.
Проблема в коде или я что-то не понимаю в работе очередей?

Comment: sidekiq же запущен при этом? То есть, в отдельном окне терминала вы выполнили команду `sidekiq`, он запустился, и в его логах вы видите что-то вроде `2018-04-04T07:13:28.895Z 94241 TID-owcjr1i0c INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop`, а после этого ничего не происходит?

Comment: @Василиса, спасибо. Я очень невнимательно читал документацию(

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: @D-side, без проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, необходимо запустить sidekiq. В отдельном окне терминала выполните команду `sidekiq`, в его логах должно появиться нечто вроде

```
2018-04-04T07:13:28.895Z 94241 TID-owcjr1i0c INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

после этого будет выполнена ваша FindRatingJob, в логах вы увидите, что она starting и done